# validate whether tables/views are created in the Test Enviroment

Tags: sql, teradata

How to validate whether the tables/views are created in the Test Enviroment in Teradata.

Comment: Check the system views, `dbc.TablesV`?

Comment: or select * from table_name, if for some reason you can't hit Dbc database

Comment: System views are D0_IM_ACQ_SAP_V.MCP_QMUR_ACQ 
D0_IM_ACQ_SAP_V.MCP_QMMA_ACQ 
D0_IM_ACQ_SAP_V.MCP_QMEL_ACQ 
D0_IM_ACQ_SAP_V.MCP_QMFE_ACQ 
D0_IM_ACQ_SAP_V.MCP_MKPF_ACQ 
D0_IM_ACQ_SAP_V.MCP_MSEG_ACQ